# Find TOMCAT 5.0.28 server start up time in windows,

Tags: windows, tomcat, java, tomcat5.5

I have two server instances TOMCAT 5.5 and TOMCAT 5.0.28, My application running on TOMCAT5.5. some body have stopped my TOMCAT5.5 and started TOMCAT 5.0.28 (May be accidentally).
Can any body help me to find the TOMCAT 5.0.28 start up and shutdown time, I have tried to find at Event viewer but couldn't get any info
I tried also at commons-daemon.log and localhost.log (may be deleted by some one) 
is there any possible way to find, other than above possiblities

Answer (score 1):

Since you don't have the logs anymore, create a JSP file and put this in it:

```
    RuntimeMXBean mx = ManagementFactory.getRuntimeMXBean();

    System.out.println("VM start time : " +  new Date(mx.getStartTime()));
    System.out.println("VM up time : " +  mx.getUptime() + " ms");
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to find a logs folder under your installation director. In there, you'll find a catalina log (or localhost or any variant) file. In this log file, you will find the information you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, But I have checked there already, where I have the files commons-daemon.log and localhost.log in log folder But they were deleted

Comment: If you have JMX enabled, use JConsole to find the uptime of the server.